# Using Javascript For..In loop on Strings gets very strange result

Tags: javascript, string, loops, for-loop

I created a string variable

```
var str = '123a'
```

I wanted to see what would happen if I used a for ... in loop to loop over it, so I ran

```
for (chars in str) {console.log(chars)}
```

But in the output, I saw...

```
0
1
2
3
d
defaultMessage
format
```

What is "d" in this case? What is defaultMessage? What is format? Why is for ... in behaving this way with strings?

Sidenote:
Running inside the chrome browser console

Comment: Did you check the docs for for..in (and maybe String)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: the docs i read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in talk exclusively about iterating objects

Comment: trying to get info about specifically where 
d
defaultMessage
format
came from. it's very strange to me, as I didn't add anything like that to the string in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'for..in' operator iterates enumerable properties in an object. Note that includes enumerable properties in the prototype chain. Since you cannot add properties to a string, seems there's some code that added

```
d
defaultMessage
format
```

to the `String.prototype` or `Object.prototype`.

Use `for..of` to enumerate characters.
`for..of` looks for `Symbol.iterator` property in an object that should refer to a method to get the object's default iterator. In case of a string its default iterator iterates characters.

```js
const str = '1234';

str.dummy = 'DUMMY';

String.prototype.d = 'd';
String.prototype.defaultMessage = 'message';
String.prototype.format = 'format';

for (const char in str) {
  console.log(char)
}

console.log('str enumerable own props:', ...Object.values(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(str)).filter(prop => prop.enumerable).map(JSON.stringify));

console.log('String.prototype enumerable own props:', ...Object.values(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(String.prototype)).filter(prop => prop.enumerable).map(JSON.stringify));

console.log('iterating default iterator implicitly');
for (const char of str) {
  console.log(char)
}

console.log('getting default iterator explicitly');
for (const char of str[Symbol.iterator]()) {
  console.log(char)
}
```